# Is this a correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Either a dryer hook-up kit or power cord and separate vent kit are required.

Basically means either

- a) dryer hook-up kit
- b) power cord and separate vent kit

are required.

The sentence sounds wrong but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds wrong because it's not written well. A better copywriter might have written:

> You will need either a dryer hook-up kit or a vent kit with separate power cord.

Answer (score 3):

As Robusto notes, this is terribly written technical English because of the ambiguity.

> (Either a dryer hook-up kit or power cord) and separate vent kit are required.

or

> Either a dryer hook-up kit or (power cord and separate vent kit) are required.

With a little bit of area knowledge you would be able to choose how it should be parsed. I cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the *either...or* construction is singular and thus calls for the singular verb *is* rather than the plural verb *are*.

Comment: Why must either...or be singular? "Either a cat and dog or a horse and pig are required" would sound ok to me. Are you suggesting "Either a cat and dog or a horse and pig is required"?

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: Yes. *Either* refers to only one of a list of items -- in your example, either a cat, a dog, a horse, or a pig, but not all of them collectively. More info [here](http://www.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/eitherare.html).

Comment: your link does not seem to back up the assertion that the choices in an either-or need to be intrinsically singular; it even says "either the puppy or the twins need". And in my example it was either the pair of cat/dog OR the pair of horse/pig.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny: More examples [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/either_or_plural_or_singular_verb.htm).

Comment: @KellyCHess: You misread the sentence. It means "Either (a cat and dog) or (a horse and pig) are required.".

Comment: @KellyCHess.  Consider also “Either the Americans or the Chinese are/*is going to top the medals table”.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Kelly's right, 'either' takes the singular, because you are choosing just one alternative from a list of items - as indeed you instinctively acknowledge: 'a (cat and dog) or a (horse and pig)'.

Comment: @DanielHarbour, transform it into a question: "Who is going to top the medals table?" . . . but you're right, transforming that into an either/or construction reads awkwardly - which is why Robusto proposes re-writing.

Comment: @StoneyB: If the choice from the list would require a plural verb then why wouldn't the list itself require a plural verb? "10 men are required. No, either 10 men or 10 women are required."

Comment: @StoneyB.  The question requires _who is_ not _who are_. But that has to do with _who_, not with _either ... or_.  Even if the predicate requires a semantically plural subject (e.g., _The troops are / *John is gathering in the hall_), the corresponding _who_ question still takes the singular (_Who is_ [not _are_] _gathering in the hall_).

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, in an either-or question, you choose just one item from the list.  However, that single list item may be either a plurality or singularity.  If it is plural, the corresponding verbs are plural.  Which is why you can’t say *_Either the Russians or the Americans is coming second_ in standard English.

Comment: @DanielHarbour Yes, my comment addressed to you was very sloppy. I should have said "which one?" not "who?", and I did not make it clear that I raised it to cast light on why 'either' takes the singular. The answer, at any rate, is to abandon a construction which creates an unresolvable grammatical collision: for instance, by saying "Either the Americans or the Chinese will top &c", or "One of two teams, either the Americans or the Chinese, is going &c"

Comment: @StoneyB.  I’m amazed.  There’s no “unresolvable grammatical collision” for me in _Either the Russians or the Americans are coming second_.  In your English, can you really not say this?  Or do you simply choose not to because of how you think one ought to speak?

Comment: @StoneyB. Quick addition.  Using _which one_ is, again, orthogonal to the _either ... or_ issue.

Comment: @DanielHarbour - Either of your alternatives is, possibly, a legitimate judgment. But I was taught that sentences of this sort should be parsed with 'either' as the singular subject. You're making me rethink this; but your use clanks on my ear; and my practice in such cases is to avoid a construction which must annoy either you or me.

Comment: @DanielHarbour And I've now consulted the OED, which (through the '87 supplement) is desperately confused and offers no parallel to the construction we're discussing - which leads me to wonder whether 'Either X or Y [predication]' is perhaps so recent a construction that usage has not shaken down to consensus?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  @KellyCHess, sorry for cluttering up your answer with all this!